# div toggle in group with fade

Tags: jquery, toggle, fade

Recently, it was requested of me to figure out how to duplicate the functionality found on this site:

http://metalabdesign.com/company/

when you click on any of the employees. I tried to comb their javascript but found it near impossible. Can someone help? I need to duplicate this functionality near perfectly.

I have put together a jsfiddle with my attempt.

http://jsfiddle.net/zGaTM/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.the-team').click(
      function() {
        $('.social-info').hide();
        $(this).next('.social-info').addClass("showdetails");
    },

    function () {
        $(this).next('.social-info').addClass("hidedetails");
    });
});
```

Comment: I don’t see anything happening there on _click_ …

Comment: I apologize I'm really new to jquery.

Comment: Have a look at this can you figure this out.[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGaTM/3/). Need to block hover event on image thats it.

Comment: BUt I need it to be on a click event, not a hover event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I create it on  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGaTM/4/) Change hover to click it will work

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.the-team').click(  //click or hover
      function() {
          $('.social-info').hide();
          $(this).next('.social-info').show();
          $(this).next('.social-info').removeClass("hidedetails");
        $(this).next('.social-info').addClass("showdetails");
    });
});
```

Div .teamCont is the main container in css put float:left; to align them horizontally. If you give opacity to main container it will apply to every child inside that container. Instead if using opacity i will suggest to use transparent PNG file as background of div social-info. It will not fade out the child elements. Or check the cSS now on [Final_JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zGaTM/7/). Please mark the answer.

Comment: it works in the fiddle perfectly!  It doesn't appear to work well when I attempt it locally.  checking my code agiain.  Thanks!

Comment: and I fixed it on my end.

Answer (score 0):

I've simplified what your trying to do: [example](http://jsfiddle.net/zGaTM/5/) - Worked from Ali Exalter's example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.teamCont').hover(
    function () {
        $(this).find("img").fadeTo("fast" , 0.1, function() { $(this).next('.social-info').show(); });
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find("img").fadeTo(100 , 1, function() { $(this).next('.social-info').hide(); }); 
    });
});
```

If you want it onclick you can call `toggle` instead of `hover` - This is just a matter of how it's triggered, the function is still the same.